# Question on non-degenerate sesquilinear forms

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, linear-transformations, dual-spaces, sesquilinear-forms

Let $f$ be a non-degenerate sesquilinear form on $E$, is it true that for all linear $\varphi$ in $E$, so $\varphi \in E^*$, there exist $z \in E$ such that $$\varphi(x) = f(x,z)$$ and if so, why?

I know that $f$ is non-degenerate if $E^{\perp} = \{0\}$, so for all non zero $z \in E$, we know that $f(x,z) \neq 0$. Does this $z$ exist because we can always modify the value of $f(x,z)$ by choosing a different $z$ and because $f$ is linear with respect to the first variable?

Would be glad if someone would help me to explain this more precisely and better, because it is not so clear for me right now.

Comment: Is $E$ finite dimensional? Do we have something like an orthonormal basis for a generic nondegenerate sesquilinear form?

Comment: Yes it is and yes there is an orthonormal basis for the $f$.

Comment: Ah, $f$ is also positive definite?

Comment: I think so, but is not very clear in the lecture. This argument was used to show the existence of the adjoint of an endomorphism form $E$ in $E$.